# MDX filter level member

Tags: mysql, ssas, mdx, mondrian

My question is how to filter valid field by another field in MDX.

I have one table: samples;
if I use sql to solve problem , just like this:

```
select patient_id from samples where calc_test_type_id = 1;
```

I created dimension for this: Patient Characteristic 
         Hierarchy: id 
         level : id (patient id in samples table) , including property, named 'testA', 'testA' linked to calc_test_type_id.

So I tried MDX like this :

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[num_samples]} ON COLUMNS,

{
  filter
       (
       distinct([Patient characteristic.id].[id].members),
       [Patient characteristic.id].CurrentMember.Properties("calc_type") = 1
       )
} ON ROWS
FROM [EIDCube]
```

`[Measures].[num_samples]` is to calculate how many rows for `calc_test_type_id = 1`.

But I found some data lost. So how to find all suitable patient id ?

Comment: If, "[Measures].[num_samples] is to calculate how many rows for calc_test_type_id = 1", why are you still having the filter in place? What is the intended output? Please add an example if possible.

Comment: Hi, the [Measures].[num_samples] is just to verify the filter result. I would like to filter patient_id like sql : select patient_id from samples where calc_test_type_id = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Try creating the set first. Also I don't think you need distinct:

```
WITH SET [calc_type1] AS
  FILTER
       (
         [Patient characteristic.id].[id].members)
        ,[Patient characteristic.id].CurrentMember.Properties("calc_type") = 1
       )
SELECT
  {[Measures].[num_samples]} ON 0,
   [calc_type1] ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
```

To check the set returned I'd be tempted to run this script without that measure first, like this:

```
WITH SET [calc_type1] AS
  FILTER
       (
         [Patient characteristic.id].[id].members)
        ,[Patient characteristic.id].CurrentMember.Properties("calc_type") = 1
       )
SELECT
  {} ON 0,
  [calc_type1] ON 1
FROM [EIDCube];
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. I think maybe the cube is wrong about this dimension. In the Patient characteristic dimension, it has id hierarchy, id hierarchy has id level, the id level column is from patient_id (sample table), and the level has property 'calc_type', 'calc_type' is from calc_test_type_id column (sample table). Perhaps the property column is linked wrong with id level (patient_id column). But I can't recognise it .

Comment: It seems mondrian can't linked level member and it's properties for same row.

Comment: I found my problem, the property doesn't support n:n relationship..thanks very much !